# rapidjson cocos2d-x parsing

Tags: c++, json, cocos2d-x, rapidjson

```
rapidjson::Document d;
    d.Parse<0>(chatevent.chat.c_str());

    if(d.HasMember("kelimeler"))
    {
        rapidjson::Value::MemberIterator M;
        const char *key,*value;

        for (M=d.MemberBegin(); M!=d.MemberEnd(); M++)
        {
            key   = M->name.GetString();
            value = M->value.GetString();

            if (key!=NULL && value!=NULL)
            {
                log("key: %s, value: %s", key,value);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code i use to handle json data in cocos2d-x. And here is the json:

```
{
    "kelimeler": [{
        "harfsayisi": 10,
        "kelime": "bibnştvdaf",
        "harfler": ["t", "s", "ç", "p", "b", "c", "h", "n", "c", "c", "n", "b", "t", "v", "ş", "v", "a", "c", "v", "p", "d", "ğ", "s", "k", "i", "ç", "f", "v", "b", "p", "a", "ü", "d", "ü", "e"]
    }]
}
```

So how to handle it using the code? I simply can not get the "kelimeler" branch. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No where in you're code does it actually get the "kelimeler" array.  See the rapidjson tutorial http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#ValueDocument

```
if(d.HasMember("kelimeler"))
{
    const Value& k = d["kelimeler"];  // you are missing this
    assert(k.IsArray());
    for (SizeType i = 0; i < k.Size(); i++) 
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I tried it before.
                          ^

Comment: Did it give you and error or wrong output. Specify whether run time or compile time error if error occured

Answer (score 1):

Need to remember to watch out for namespace collisions. Ideally the compiler warns about ambiguity. In your case you need to specify you want the classes from rapidjson and not cocos2d.

Updating Josh's example.

```
rapidjson::Document d;
d.Parse<0>(chatevent.chat.c_str());
if(d.HasMember("kelimeler"))
{
    const rapidjson::Value& k = d["kelimeler"];  // you are missing this
    assert(k.IsArray());
    if(k.HasMember("harfler")) 
    {
        const rapidjson::Value& h = k["harfler"];
        for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < h.Size(); i++) 
        {
             log("value: %s", h[i].GetString());
        }
    }
}
```